# Why does the hello-word image output only for the first time?

Tags: docker

I installed Docker and then ran `docker run hello-world` which appears to run correctly with that "Hello from Docker message".

However, on subsequent `docker container start cool_robinson`, I do not see the same terminal output as I saw the first time:

```
pi@Pavillion:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                 NAMES
46f651f9edf8        hello-world         "/hello"                 18 hours ago        Exited (0) 10 minutes ago                         cool_robinson

pi@Pavillion:~$ docker container start cool_robinson
cool_robinson
pi@Pavillion:~$
```

I am not familiar with C, but isn't the `main` function in hello.c executed every time the container is run?

Comment: How does the C main function is involved here? If you have some C commands specified in RUN it will only exec during the build. You should use CMD or ENTRYPOINT if you want that command to be called every new container run

Comment: I was refering to the source code of the `hello-world` image.

Comment: It justs outputs the name of the container, you should provide `-a` flag to see container's output in the console.

Comment: In routine use I'd suggest `docker rm cool_robinson` to clean up the previous run, and then you can `docker run hello-world` again in a clean environment.  Or you can `docker run --rm` to have it clean itself up.  I rarely use `docker start` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the container with `docker run`, it starts the container in the foreground and so that's is why you see the container logs in the terminal.

```
docker run hello-world
```

So it stop as its just print hello message and die.

and when you start the same container again, it print message but in detach mode and does not allocate tty, to checks logs you need to run two command.

```
docker container start cool_robinson
docker logs cool_robinson
```

You will see hello message two times.

Or you can try with `attache mode to run in foreground with container command as mentioned by @Leopal.

```
docker container start  -a cool_robinson
```